# How to rewrite URL to include variables and remove php while allowing directories

Tags: php, apache, variables, mod-rewrite, directory

I have the following htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?user=$1
```

which works as expected for example

```
http://example.com/index.php?user=USERNAME -> http://example.com/USERNAME
```

However I have created a form on the page index.php which posts to /directory/save.php

How do I remove .php while allowing for the directory so that I can post to /directory/save/ instead?

Comment: If there is a file in `/directory/save.php` it should take you there... Isn't that what `!-f` is supposed to do?

Comment: That is what I understood from the rewrite manual however it still doesn't work. It takes me to index.php?user=directory/save instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it is going to one and only such file in `/directory` then probably hard code it by adding following before the above rules?

```
RewriteRule ^directory/save$ /directory/save.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

directory/ might have it's own rewrite rules and not have a physical save.php, that's why !-f might not work. Try adding a new rewrite condition to stop rewriting for directory/

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^directory
```

Comment: Great, so now directory/save/ doesn't go to index.php?user=directory/save/ but 404's instead. How can I rewrite directory/save.php to directory/save/

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this one if it's rewriting */directory/save.php* file to directory */directory/save/*

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/directory/save\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.+) /directory/save/ [NC]
```